# How can i prevent opening the window on outside click?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I wanted to build custom autocomplete.
I found this youtube tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MN-pi2GMw4
The complete solution for this tutorial is here - (You don't need to watch whole 12 minutes video )
https://github.com/Bigless27/custom-autocomplete.

So he is using `dropdown.directive.ts` to detect when the user click outside to close the window under the input

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]',
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    @Output() public clickOutside = new EventEmitter();
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {

    }

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    public onClick(targetElement) {
        const isClickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!isClickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(null);
        }
    }
}
```

but there is a bug.If the window is closed - and the user clicks outside then the window is opened.
How can i solve this with this clickOutside directive here ?

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: I posted an answer.Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0):

@Sdsd, you only need "check" if the "window" is closed or not. I don't see the video, but It's only

```
 closeDropDown() {
    this.showDropDown = !this.showDropDown;
  }
```

```
  //replace by
 closeDropDown() {
    this.showDropDown = false;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I found a way and posted an answer. Btw it will not work with your suggested answer because on that way  the window will always remain closed because with the directive that he is using - the closeDropdown gets executed always - on evert click on the page and that means and even the input is clicked it will emit false value.

Answer (score 0):

So i've found a way...

His proiblem was that he always get false in

```
const isClickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
```

after that there is check if it is false call the function clickOutside

So the code that is working

**dropdown directive**

```
import { Directive,Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]',
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    @Output() public clickOutside = new EventEmitter();
    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    public onClick(targetElement) {
        if(targetElement.id == "search") {
            this.clickOutside.emit('open');
        } else {
            this.clickOutside.emit(null);
        }
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<header class='flex-container flex-center'>
    <div class='width-25'></div>
    <div class="width-half">
        <label for="search">
            <i class='fa fa-search icon-pos color-purple'></i>
        </label>
        <form [formGroup]='stateForm' autocomplete="new-password" novalidate>
            <input id="ok" autocomplete="off" id='search' placeholder="Search for a state" formControlName='search' (click)=' openDropDown() ' class=' input-underline search-bar ' type='text'>
        </form>
        <div clickOutside (clickOutside)="closeDropDown($event)">
            <div *ngIf='showDropDown' class='search-drop-down '>
                <div (click)='selectValue(s)' (blur)="toggleAC()" class='search-results ' *ngFor="let s of states | searchFilter: getSearchValue()">
                    <a [innerHTML]="s | letterBold: getSearchValue()">
                           {{s}}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='width-25 '></div>
</header>
```

**the modified method in the typescript file - closeDropDown + i deleted the openDropDown - we don't need anymore**

```
  closeDropDown(ev) {
    if(ev == "open") {
      this.showDropDown = true;
    } else {
      this.showDropDown = false;
    }
  }
```

so now we have a directive that is listening - where the user is clicking - it will give us the clicked node element from the DOM - we then check in the directive if that clicked node element's id is `search` because in the app.component.html we have the input with id `search`.If it is then we call - closeDropDown to assign value true to `showDropDown` boolean and the input autocomplete window will be opened.if not - it will be false and the winwod will be closed ( if previous was opened ) or if it is not it will remain close.So on this way i solved the bug